# C# making WebBrowser wait until page loads

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to make my WebBrowser wait until the page fully loads, then proceed to the next step. I've research how to do this, yet, my code keeps running before the page loads.

```
private void AdobeConnect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++)
        {
            while (acBrwsr.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            adobeStepper(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't you just wait for the completed event?

Comment: `WebBrowser` do provide `Completed` event.

Comment: `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` Event

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are relying on ReadyState and you shouldn't be.  In WebBrowser.DocumentComplete you need to check e.Url == WebBrowser.Url then check for the ready state.  DocumentComplete fires multiple times with forms when you have frames and that messes with ReadyState.

What I do with my bots that use WebBrowser is I activate a timer when I have a document complete state for the actual page then grab my next item in the queue to process for that page like 1 second after the completion.  (Of course always turn off the timer in the OnTick event.)

I wrote a queue that groups a set of tasks together where I can prioritize and remove any items like a list so I don't repeat tasks but only perform when DocumentCompleted e.url == webBrowser.url and my ReadyState is Complete.